# Run a function in main only no in sidebar

Tags: wordpress, function

I have a function and i used the hook "get_comment_author_link" for my function. Now i want to run the function only in the main page. But not in the sidebar.Is there any function in wordpress to restrict the function in sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar is usually a separate php file which is included in the template using 'get_template_part' or 'get_sidebar'. I can't find a proper filter for this, so probably you'll have to figure out another approach to the task.